# iPhone SDK Add Image to the Body of an Email?

Tags: iphone, image, email, sdk

I was wondering if anyone knew how to use an image in the body of an email when the mail app is opened. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance Kieran.

Comment: Duplicate?  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819021/iphone-how-can-i-embed-images-in-email-from-my-app) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534217/display-local-image-in-iphone-html-mail)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can attach image in mail body using base64 encoding

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
NSString *imageStr = [imageData base64EncodingWithLineLength:[imageData length]];

NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".....<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,%@'>.......",imageStr];

[mailComposer setMessageBody:htmlStr isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
        [mailComposer release];
```

Answer (score 10):

```
NSData *photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"qwerty.png"], 1);
MFMailComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[viewController addAttachmentData:photoData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo.png"]];
```

I wrote the code by hand so it might have some mistake, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. It worked fine but when I click the button nothing happens?