# How to attach images in Mail Composer?

Tags: iphone, email

I want to use Mail Composer which should attach an image file also, how is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - how can I embed images in email from my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819021/iphone-how-can-i-embed-images-in-email-from-my-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to attach an image the test code provided on the other answer should work but as a second source the same code located at Apress at this url [Mail Pic](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/701/) should be able to assist you with a working example. Download the folder and open the MailPic folder for the project file.

Answer (score 15):

You can test this code, it's perfectly working...

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailController setSubject:@"Hello iPhone"];

    [mailController setMessageBody:@"This is the MailSend Application...." isHTML:NO];

    UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image box with border-1.png"];
    NSData *exportData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic ,1.0);
    [mailController addAttachmentData:exportData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Picture.jpeg"];


    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
    [mailController release];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailController 

didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 

{

        [self becomeFirstResponder];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

For More Information with sample Code Check here

http://iosrider.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/how-to-add-email-and-message-in-your-native-application/