# Adding Image as an attachment to email

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can send a file as attachment in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302403/how-can-send-a-file-as-attachment-in-objective-c)

I want to add an image as an attachment in my iPhone application.Now I am attaching the image like this:

```
NSMutableString * body = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body><img src=\"http://url here\"/>"];
[body appendString:@"</body></html>"];
[mailer setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
```

But instead of url I want to include an image which is in my resource folder.

How can I do the same?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049259/iphone-sdk-add-image-to-the-body-of-an-email , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819021/iphone-how-can-i-embed-images-in-email-from-my-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534217/display-local-image-in-iphone-html-mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From apple documentation about MFMailComposeViewController; basically you must init the UIImage with your image, extract the image data (e.g.: if it is a PNG use UIImagePNGRepresentation()) and provide the right mime type e.g. image/png. Then use the specified function below (the file name is a name of a file you want to give to the attachment; e.g. "image.png")

```
addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:
Adds the specified data as an attachment to the message.

- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename

Parameters
attachment
The data to attach. Typically, this is the contents of a file that you want to include. This parameter must not be nil.
mimeType
The MIME type of the specified data. (For example, the MIME type for a JPEG image is image/jpeg.) For a list of valid MIME types, see http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/. This parameter must not be nil.
filename
The preferred filename to associate with the data. This is the default name applied to the file when it is transferred to its destination. Any path separator (/) characters in the filename are converted to underscore (_) characters prior to transmission. This parameter must not be nil.
Discussion
This method attaches the specified data after the message body but before the user’s signature. You may attach multiple files (using different file names) but must do so prior to displaying the mail composition interface. Do not call this method after presenting the interface to the user.
```

Example:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_bundled_image"];
NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
[mailComposerViewController addAttachmentData:myImageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:"my_image.png"];
```